# C# - LINQ to XML - Saving doc add extra spaces in the formatting

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Opening and saving an XML used for Visio formats the XML adding in spaces. These spaces are fine for the most part except for the part where they are used to write the actual text to the diagrams. I'm a little lost on what can be done with this. I've tried disabling formatting when saving but that outputs the exact same thing.

```
public void TestSave(string page)
        {
            string xmlFile = @"page" + page + ".xml";
            string xmlPath = Path.Combine(ExtractPath, @"visio\pages\", xmlFile);
            XElement pageContents = XElement.Load(xmlPath);
            pageContents.Save(xmlPath);
        }
```

This is what it looks like before the save

[image]

[image][image]

This is what it looks like after the save

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the save set up incorrectly for disable formatting. The correct way below. This has solved my space issue.

```
public void TestSave(string page)
        {
            string xmlFile = @"page" + page + ".xml";
            string xmlPath = Path.Combine(ExtractPath, @"visio\pages\", xmlFile);
            XElement pageContents = XElement.Load(xmlPath);
            pageContents.Save(xmlPath, SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
        }
```